# Web-mapping with editing capabilities?

Tags: web-mapping, editing

I'm embarking on a new web map project that seeks to display simple geometries (lines, points, polygons) and rasters/basemaps. Ideally, the map will also allow authorized users to add/remove/edit geometries and their attributes.

What are the available options for the storage of data (e.g. SQL Server Spatial)?

What are the available options for the presentation of data (e.g. ArcGIS Server)?

I'm new to web mapping and am attempting to build a solid understanding of the available options and their pros/cons.

Comment: have you looked at [Geoserver](http://geoserver.org) and [openlayers](http://openlayers.org)?

Comment: I've seen some simple maps that use both of the above options, such as the examples on their respective homepages. Do either of these technologies allow for more complex functions such as handling features and feature editing?

Comment: There are better examples on their site, but [in this example](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/editing-methods.html#) double click the cursor on the map. If you look at their examples page, there are a few options for you to consider.

Comment: + 1 @ dassouki. I just went through several of the examples and the functionality looks promising. Is anyone aware of a web map which contains many of these editing features in more of a "production" environment?

Comment: Take a look to OpneGeo suite (http://opengeo.org/). They offer enterprise support, so it shows you that software has future :)

Comment: geoext is also another one to look at. http://geoext.org/examples.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look to OpenLayers for client side, it offers in a simply way all you seems need.
As previously suggest to you by Dassouki, take a look to the example page: http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/ find for 'edit'
For example: http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/editingtoolbar.html

For server side I personally bet for OS project, IMO they are incredible good quality and there is nothing they need to envy to proprietary software:
GeoServer + PostgreSQL/PostGIS

Answer (score 5):

You might want to try Geoserver in the back-end and use OpenGeo's [GXP](http://2011.foss4g.org/sessions/introducing-gxp-webmapping-made-easy) on the front end. GXP is a client-side javascript library that's built on top of **OpenLayers, GeoExt and ExtJS** ( now Sencha ). It's supposed to bridge the gap between OpenLayers and full blown web applications. A framework if you will.

[Here's](http://workshops.opengeo.org/gxp/) a handy guide for getting started with GXP. An example of an app created with GXP is the OpenGeo Suite's GeoExplorer. It's a map viewer, styler and editor.

[image]

Comment: The GXP link is dead. GXP is available here: https://github.com/boundlessgeo/gxp